# How to use Glass Mapper's BeginEditFrame(string buttons, string dataSource, string title)

Tags: experience-editor, glass-mapper

I've created my own `custom experience button` to edit some responsive images for a logo in my header and I added the button to the `rendering`. It works as expected and I am not having any problems with it.

However, I would like to move the button to an edit frame using `Glass Mapper's BeginEditFrame` so that the content manager can just click on some placeholder text to access the custom button.

I'm trying to use the edit frame with this signature - `BeginEditFrame`(string buttons, string dataSource, string title).

My code is as follows:

```
using (BeginEditFrame("{CDA69877-442C-47CC-87D3-E1D2BF61E5B8}", "{6F455DBC-29FE-40FC-9803-0A738677EC04}", "Logo Images"))
{
    <p>Click here to edit the logo.</p>
}
```

The first Guid represents the ID of my custom button. The second Guid represents the datasource item containing my logo images.

I also tried using the filepaths instead of Guids but got the same results.

In case it helps, my button is found at `/sitecore/content/Applications/WebEdit/Custom Experience Buttons/Responsive Images`

And my datasource item is at `/sitecore/content/siteroot/Data/Headers/Header`

I don't get any errors with this code, but the edit frame that pops up does not have anything useful. I've pasted it below.

[image: Edit Frame Pop-up]

1. Am I correct in using my custom button `filepath/Guid` for the buttons parameter? (Edit: I just figured this part out. I needed to use the `filepath/Guid` for the folder containing the buttons and not the filepath/Guid for the button item itself.)
2. And is the `datasource` item that holds the logos in question the datasource parameter that the method signature is asking for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out.

1. For the buttons parameter, I needed to use the filepath/Guid for the folder continaing the buttons I want to be displayed on the edit frame.
2. This worked when I used the Guid of the datasource item containing my logo images, which is what I thought it should be. I'm not sure why it didn't work initially.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using `Glass Mapper 5` then you can apply `EditFrame` using below code:

```
@using (Html.Glass().BeginEditFrame(Model.HeroBanner, "Edit Banner", m => m.BannerImage,
    m => m.BannerNavigation, m => m.ShowSameMessage, m => m.HideSection))
{
    <div class="background" style="@(Model.HeroBanner.BannerImage != null ? "background-image: url(" + Model.HeroBanner.BannerImage.Src + ")" : "")">
        @if (Model.HeroBanner.BannerNavigation)
        {
            <div class="heading">
                <div class="@(Model.HeroBanner.HeaderStyle != null ? Model.HeroBanner.HeaderStyle.CssClass : "heading-2")">
                    @Html.Glass().Editable(Model.HeroBanner, m => m.BannerTitle)
                </div>
            </div>
        }
        if (!Model.HeroBanner.HideSection)
        {
        <div class="section">
        </div>
        }
    </div>
}
```

Here `Mode.HeroBanner` is Model Class and BannerImage, BannerNavigation, ShowSameMesage, and HideSection are the Class properties.

It will allow you to edit all the above properties to edit in `EditFrame`, you don't need to create any `Custom Experience Button`.